How to manipulate Actions in Watson Assistant via APIs
I'm trying to populate Watson assistant (that is part of Watson orchestrate) action.  Looking at the documentation, it states

If you need to change a skill programmatically (rather than by using the watsonx Assistant user interface), you can use the workspace authoring methods that are provided by the v1 API.

Problem is the V1 APIs it points to are for the legacy style of APIs (i.e., intents, entities, ...) and not the new style with Actions/skills.  Can anyone point me to the right APIs to use?

There is no API that allows you to programatically create Actions. Modifying the JSON and pushing that way puts your assistant in an unsupported configuration.
